# c# / c++ interop and out allocated array by c++

Tags: c#

I have a thirdparty c++ method in a dll like this:

```
void GetValues(int *pCount, int **ppValues);
```

c++ usage would be:

```
int count = 0, *pValues = NULL;
GetValues(&count, &pValues);
CoTaskMemFree(pValues);
```

I want to call this method in c#:
it is declared as :

```
void GetValues([out] int pCount, IntPtr ppValues);
```

c# usage (the method using this code is marked as unsafe):

```
   int *pValues = null;
    try
    {
       int count;
       GetValues(out count, new IntPtr(&pValues));
       for (var i=0; i<count; i++)
       {
           var val = pValues[i];
       }
    }
    finally
    {
       Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(new IntPtr(pValues));
    }
```

this seems to work.
But I'm wondering if this is correct or if there are problems with this approach I didin't see.

EDIT: 
changed c# declaration from 
void GetValues([out] int pCount, [out] IntPtr ppValues);
to
void GetValues([out] int pCount, IntPtr ppValues);

Comment: Should this be on codereview.SE since it works?

Comment: if you're using managed-C++ just use a [managed array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtbydz1t.aspx) then you don't need any unsafe code. Also this is dangerous... you're freeing the memory before C# has a chance to access it.

Comment: Almo: I said "it seems to work". I have never seen anyone do this kind of stuffs this way. Hence my question

Comment: Mgetz: I can't use managed c++ to wrap this. This should work as such on linux with mono

Comment: @user1968335 you marked the question with [tag:managed-C++], I have to assume that you're using C++/CLI

Comment: I would suggest reading how to [Marshal arrays using PInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd99e6zt.aspx)

Comment: Mgetz: I'm not freeing the array before c# use. That c++ code was just to show how I'd use it in c++.

Comment: Mgetz: sorry for the confusion. Marking with managed-c++ was an error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something, but "out" prefix is missing in call `GetValues(out count, new IntPtr(&pValues));`

I would solve this problem simpler:

```
        unsafe void test()
    {
        IntPtr intPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            int count = 0;
            GetValues(out count, out intPtr);

            int* pValues = (int*)intPtr;

            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var val = pValues[i];
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(intPtr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are missing something, [OutAttribute] is not related to the `out` keyword.

Comment: But it still doesn't compile (in c#). It should be something like this: static int GetValues([Out] out int count, [Out] out IntPtr data);

Comment: Slava: I made an error while typing the c# declaration. When the second parameter is [out] your code works.